# Using javascript date object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using datepicker.js and it is returning a date object from the input.

```
    Console[Log] Object (test.html, line 229)
    date: 16
    day: 4
    month: 0
    obj: Thu Jan 16 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)
      __proto__: NaN
    pick: 1389855600000
    year: 2014
       __proto__: Object
```

I need to create labels for the next inputs based on this information. How do I change this object into the following format

Jan 16

and then I am running a loop to create the inputs/labels so how do i increment that based on the user choosing a number from a drop down list. Essentially if the first date picked is Jan 16, then I need Jan 17, Jan 18 etc.

Comment: You might want to check out this very helpful library http://momentjs.com/. A few minutes in their documentation will give you exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: This cured it. I was trying to stay away from loading another JS library on my page, however, this one takes care of everything.If you answer this post with this info, I will mark it answered

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

As requested: you might want to check out [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), an awesome library for dealing with the terribleness of Date objects.